# How to read a text file with string into a ´n undirected graph with adjacency list

Tags: java

Newbie here! I want to implement a class Graph that can represent an un-weighted and undirected graph using Adjacency Lists. The basic functionality should include adding and removing vertices and edges, as well as printing the graph to command line.
My main problem is that I'm having a hard time to read the file into the graph. What I am doing wrong?

My text file look like this:

```
Anna    Noah
Anna    Marie
Marie   Noah
Marie   Jakob
Marie   Hanna
Jakob   Felix
Hanna   Felix
Hanna   Jonas
Felix   Jonas
Felix   Emma
Felix   Finn
Felix   Ben
```

(each line represents two nodes connected by an edge).

My code is:

```
public class UndirectedGraphs {
HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> socialNetworkAdj;

public UndirectedGraphs() {
    socialNetworkAdj = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>();


}
public void addVertex(String label){
    socialNetworkAdj.put(label, new LinkedList<String>());
}

public LinkedList<String> getEdges(String label) {
    return socialNetworkAdj.get(label);
}

public void addEdges(String ver1, String ver2) {
    if (!socialNetworkAdj.containsKey(ver1)) {
        addVertex(ver1);
    }

    if (!socialNetworkAdj.containsKey(ver2)) {
        addVertex(ver2);
    }
    socialNetworkAdj.get(ver1).add(ver2);
    socialNetworkAdj.get(ver2).add(ver1);
    System.out.println(socialNetworkAdj);

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File filePath = new File("C:\\Users\\Fo\\Desktop\\A9\\network.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String[] tokens = new String[2];
    ArrayList<String> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    UndirectedGraphs graph = new UndirectedGraphs();
    String line;
    String var1 = tokens[0];
    String var2 = tokens[1];

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        graph.addEdges(var1, var2);
    }
    System.out.println("\nAnna: --> " + graph.getEdges("Anna"));
    br.close();

}
```

}

The Output is:

```
{null=[null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
{null=[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]}
```

Comment: Inside the `while` loop, you need to split each `line` read and send the results of that to the `addEdges` function. `String [] nodes = line.split("\\s+"); if (nodes.length == 2) graph.addEdges(nodes[0], nodes[1]);`

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, at each iteration of the while loop you need to get the names of the read line, and add them while iterating.

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] nodes = line.split("\\s+");
    if(nodes.length == 2)
        graph.addEdges(nodes[0], nodes[1]);
    // optional else with error handling
}
```